# Finding out unread mails which do not have certain keywords included in the subject in my mailbox using Mail gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I am able to read the unread emails with the word "development" from my mailbox using:

```
Mail.find(keys: ['UNSEEN','SUBJECT',"development"],:count => 100,:what =>:all).
```

I now want to retrieve the unread mails from my mailbox with out the word "development" in subject line.

I read [RFC2060](http://james.apache.org/server/rfclist/imap4/rfc2060.txt), section 6.4.4, and tried UNKEYWORD AND NOT methods, but it didn't help. Can anybody suggest me an appropriate answer for the same?

Answer (score 1):

Note that it is an IMAP query, so it uses [Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) :

```
Mail.find(keys: ['UNSEEN', 'NOT', 'SUBJECT',"development"],:count => 100,:what =>:all)
```

It worked on my computer with Gmail IMAP.

One problem was that an Unseen mail was considered Seen as soon as I retrieved it to check `subject` and `from`.

Comment: If a have a couple of words which shouldn't be included in the subject line, it doesn't work when i include all the words after SUBJECT tag.For eg:- Mail.find(keys: ['UNSEEN','NOT','SUBJECT',["Development","Uat"]],:count => 100,:what =>:all)

Comment: Do you find any solution for this Mr Eric Duminil? Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot test it, but it should be something like `['UNSEEN', 'NOT', 'SUBJECT','word1', 'NOT', 'SUBJECT', 'word2']`